# Custom dropout layer implementation

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement custom dropout layer. During forward propagation, I'd like my inputs to pass as it is without any dropout. During backward pass, I'd like to update gradient of only some inputs while freezing gradient of others. This would be based on a probability which decides what gradients to update and what to freeze.

I have implemented a custom layer, however as the modification is subtle, it is difficult to verify if it is correct. It is possible to get reasonable output with incorrect implementation. I have modified existing dropout function in Keras.

```
class MyDropout(Layer):
    """Applies Dropout to the input.
    Dropout consists in randomly setting
    a fraction `rate` of input units to 0 at each update during training time,
    which helps prevent overfitting.
    # Arguments
        rate: float between 0 and 1. Fraction of the input units to drop.
        noise_shape: 1D integer tensor representing the shape of the
            binary dropout mask that will be multiplied with the input.
            For instance, if your inputs have shape
            `(batch_size, timesteps, features)` and
            you want the dropout mask to be the same for all timesteps,
            you can use `noise_shape=(batch_size, 1, features)`.
        seed: A Python integer to use as random seed.
    # References
        - [Dropout: A Simple Way to Prevent Neural Networks from Overfitting](
           http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume15/srivastava14a/srivastava14a.pdf)
    """
    def __init__(self, rate, noise_shape=None, seed=None, **kwargs):
        super(MyDropout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rate = min(1., max(0., rate))
        self.noise_shape = noise_shape
        self.seed = seed
        self.supports_masking = True

    def _get_noise_shape(self, inputs):
        if self.noise_shape is None:
            return self.noise_shape

        symbolic_shape = keras.backend.shape(inputs)
        noise_shape = [symbolic_shape[axis] if shape is None else shape
                       for axis, shape in enumerate(self.noise_shape)]
        return tuple(noise_shape)


    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        if 0. < self.rate < 1.:
            noise_shape = self._get_noise_shape(inputs)

            # generate random number of same shape as input
            uniform_random_number = keras.backend.random_normal(shape=keras.backend.shape(inputs))
            # check where the random number if greater than the dropout rate
            indices_greater_than = tf.greater(uniform_random_number,self.rate,name = 'stoppedGradientLocations')
            indices_greater_than = tf.cast(indices_greater_than,dtype=tf.float32)
            inputs_copy = tf.identity(inputs)
            out1 = tf.stop_gradient(inputs_copy*indices_greater_than)
            indices_less_than= 1 - indices_greater_than
            out2 = inputs*indices_less_than
            out_total = out1 + out2


        return out_total

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'rate': self.rate,
                  'noise_shape': self.noise_shape,
                  'seed': self.seed}
        base_config = super(Dropout, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```

What is the best way to verify my implementation - is the code working as intended?